# winapi сохранение png из буфера обмена

Tags: winapi, изображения

Добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста получить изображение из буфера обмена.

```
            if (OpenClipboard)
            {
                HBITMAP hImg = (HBITMAP)GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);
                if (hImg)
                {

                }
                CloseClipboard();
            }
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы сохранить содержимое в файл в PNG-формате?
Я к WinAPI прибегаю достаточно редко, но сейчас требуется именно это. Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: Нужен именно PNG?

Comment: Да. Только PNG.

Answer (score 1):

GDI, [вроде как](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371129/5045688), не поддерживает PNG, поэтому будем использовать GDI+.

Описание, как подключить GDI+ взято [отсюда](https://rsdn.org/article/gdi/gdiplus1.xml#EJCAC).

В файл `stdafx.h` добавляем:

```
#include <GdiPlus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
```

Комментируем в нём строку

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
```

В файл `stdafx.cpp` добавляем:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "GdiPlus.lib")
```

В начало функции `WinMain` добавляем код инициализации:

```
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput; 
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken; 
GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
```

В её конец добавляем код очистки:

```
GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
```

---

Само сохранение элементарно:

```
if (OpenClipboard(hWnd))
{
    HBITMAP hImg = (HBITMAP)GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);
    if (hImg)
    {
        Bitmap bmp(hImg, nullptr);
        CLSID pngClsid;
        GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);
        bmp.Save(L"image.png", &pngClsid, NULL);
    }
    CloseClipboard();
}
```

Обратите внимание, в функцию `OpenClipboard` нужно передавать хэндл окна: `hWnd`.

---

Код функции `GetEncoderClsid` взят [отсюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms533843.aspx).

```
int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
    UINT  num = 0;          // number of image encoders
    UINT  size = 0;         // size of the image encoder array in bytes

    ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if (size == 0)
        return -1;  // Failure

    pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if (pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
        return -1;  // Failure

    GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);

    for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0)
        {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;  // Success
        }
    }

    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return -1;  // Failure
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. К сожалению,HBITMAP hImg = (HBITMAP)GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP); возвращает NULL.
Но при этом BOOL isPic = IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_BITMAP); = 1 (true). Как такое возможно?

Comment: @Viktor - без хендла в `OpenClipboard` не работает. С этим параметром - у меня работает. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало.

Comment: Скажите, а при  Bitmap bmp(hImg, nullptr) создается копия изображения в памяти? Если перед сохранением в файл (но после создания объекта Bitmap) в буфере окажется уже не изображение, что произойдет?

Comment: @Viktor - да, создаётся копия.